# C# Разделение Extension методов

Tags: c#

Есть Три проекта (для простоты будут `A,B,C`). Теперь сама проблема:

В проектах A и B есть экстеншн метод с одинаковой сигнатурой `T Copy<T>(this T)`.
К проекту C прекручены A и B, нужно вызвать метод .Copy , есть ли возможность как нибудь разделить реализации?

Comment: Ну так вы в using указывайте нужное пространство имен с нужным вам классом с методами расширения.

Comment: Либо пишите явно с указанием класса: `NamespaceA.ExtensionsClass.Copy(source)`

Comment: @tym32167 в using указанны оба класса, и оба вроде используются

Comment: @АндрейNOP, выносите в ответ

Comment: Я в таких случаях использую [псевдонимы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive), примерно так: `using Extensions = B.Extensions;` и все, данный класс принимает расширения нужной реализации, а если надо использовать другую, то как сказали выше, указываю явно `namespace`.

Comment: здрастье https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315985/objecta-%d0%b8-objectb-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишите вызов явно, с указанием класса (как для обычного не-extension статического метода):

```
var result = NamespaceA.ExtensionsClass.Copy(source);
```